# Unable to connect container port from localhost when network_mode: "bridge" (docker-compose)

Tags: networking, docker, localhost, containers, docker-compose

This is my `docker-compose.yml`

`yml
version: '2'
services:
  admin_db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgres.dockerfile
      args:
        - DB_NAME=admin_db
        - DB_USER=admin
        - DB_PASSWORD=admin_pass
    network_mode: "default"
  admin:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: admin.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=$UID
        - GID=$GID
        - UNAME=$UNAME
    command: /bin/bash
    depends_on:
      - admin_db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    links:
     - admin_db
    network_mode: "bridge"`

If with networking_mode:"bridge" I should be able to access my app (admin) on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` from localhost, but currently, I'm able to access it only on `random-ip:8000` from localhost. 
I'm able to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` access when networking_mode is "host", but then I'm unable to link containers.
Is there any solution to have both things ?
- linked containers
- app running on http://127.0.0.1:8000/ from localhost

Comment: What happens if you just leave off the "network_mode" from all the services? Should work the way you desire by default. (Certainly having different network modes spec'd is going to make things more complicated.)

Comment: when no "network_mode" in config then I'm able to access my app only on `random-ip:8000`

Comment: Are you running on MacOS, Windows, or using docker-machine?

Answer (score 0):

If for some unknown reason normal linking doesn't work you can always create another bridged network and connect directly to that docker image. By doing that IP address of that running image will always be the same.

I would edit it like this:

```
version: '2'
services:
  admin_db:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: postgres.dockerfile
      args:
        - DB_NAME=admin_db
        - DB_USER=admin
        - DB_PASSWORD=admin_pass
    networks:
      back_net:
        ipv4_address: 11.0.0.2

  admin:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: admin.dockerfile
      args:
        - UID=$UID
        - GID=$GID
        - UNAME=$UNAME
    command: /bin/bash
    depends_on:
      - admin_db
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    extra_hosts:
      - "admin_db:11.0.0.2"
    networks:
      back_net:
        ipv4_address: 11.0.0.3

networks:
  back_net:
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.enable_ipv6: "false"
      com.docker.network.bridge.name: "back"
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 11.0.0.0/24
          gateway: 11.0.0.1
```

Hope that helps.